# how to put array to dict with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have batch of data with same class .dev
and I want to use each to put each of them to an dict
for example

```
<input class='dev' value='a'>
<input class='dev' value='b'>
<input class='dev' value='c'>
<input class='dev' value='d'>

info = { 
name:'',
id:'',
country:'',
desc:''}

$('.dev').each(function(i){           
          $(this).val();
        })
```

and I can get

```
info = { 
'name':'a',
'id':'b',
'country':'c',
'desc':'d'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over properties and assign values -

```js
let info = {
  name: '',
  id: '',
  country: '',
  desc: ''
};
let index = 0;
for (const key in info) {
  info[key] = $('.dev')[index++].value;
}
console.log(info);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='dev' value='a'>
<input class='dev' value='b'>
<input class='dev' value='c'>
<input class='dev' value='d'>
```